# ggplot - How do I make a box plot showing two columns on the x-axis with numerical values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to create a boxplot with two categories on the x-axis, the intact_fooddepth and the hulled_fooddepth.  I'm not sure how to manipulate the data in order to achieve this and create a boxplot in ggplot.

This is the data set I'm working with.  I'm also using dplyr to familiarize myself with it if that helps

[image]

I've tried using the group_by method with dplyr but I'm not sure if I understand how to use it correctly

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: You can use `pivot_longer` to create a single variable with the intact and hulled fooddepth data, and pass the new pair of columns to ggplot for your boxplot.

Answer (score 1):

As your variables are in different columns it's best to reshape your data to long format before plotting, i.e. do

```
dat %>% 
  select(intact_fooddepth, hulled_fooddepth) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(variable, value)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

This way your variables become categories of a new column `variable` with corresponding values in a new column `value`. The `variable` column could then be mapped on `x` and the values on `y`. Note: To make my life easier I use the `select` to include only the desired columns in the final dataset used for the plot.

And using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, hp) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(variable, value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is amazing.  I'll definitely be using this feature in the future!